Flutter local notification not coming when app is closed when i set a reminder
1.When i set a reminder on the device it is not working when the app is closed
2.When i set a reminder notification on the device it is working only when the app is open which i don't want before it was showing notification even when the app is closed
3.After updating to the new android studio this problem started since then notification if the app is closed does not show.
4.The app is not migrated to latest flutter and dart still using the old one
here is my code

class NotifyHelper {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin(); //

  initializeNotification() async {

    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,

    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: selectNotification);
  }



  Future selectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      print('notification payload: $payload');
    } else {
      print("Notification Done");
    }

  }


  displayNotification({@required String title, @required String body}) async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            showWhen: false);
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .show(0, title, body, platformChannelSpecifics, payload: 'item x');
  }



  periodicalyNotification() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails('repeating channel id',
            'repeating channel name', 'repeating description');
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(0, 'repeating title',
        'repeating body', RepeatInterval.everyMinute, platformChannelSpecifics,
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true);
  }
}

1.I tried updating the API nothing
2.I tried to search on google and YouTube i couldn't find a suitable solution.
3.I also tried to check if the app is allowed to show notification on physical devices which it showed allowed
but on the latest phones it is locked it does not show allowed it shows locked
4.I tried changing the channel nothing
It has been now 3 weeks just trying to find the solution
EXPECTATIONS

I was expecting the app alarm to ring with the notification showing the title and the body which it used to Show but now it has stopped


My Manifest file

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />

   <application
        android:label="Astartasks"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

       <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
       <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"  android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
                />

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

